# Transfer database from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, database-migration

I already have a database in SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition.

It contains :

- tables
- views
- procedures
- objects

Now I want to downgrade the database to SQL Server 2008 Enterprise edition. I know there is no direct option. I tried to  backup on 2012 and then restore on 2008. Not working.

Any Idea on how to completely transfer database ?

Comment: Voted to move to dba.stack

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Database in SQL Server 2012, Script and Use in 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303791/create-database-in-sql-server-2012-script-and-use-in-2008)

Comment: See here as well: http://superuser.com/questions/468578/move-database-from-sql-server-2012-to-2008

Comment: why not try SQL Server Data Tools http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx

Comment: Another answer [here uses BCP](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15682/sql-server-2012-backward-compatibility-for-backups-with-2008/102858#102858) which I've found easier.

Comment: The answers confused me a bit when I had the same prob yesterday. I ended up using MS Management Studio and when you right-click on the db there, it's as easy as Task>Export data. It actually offered to import that same data and I was able to get it into 2008 simply with that function! :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must export the database as text (.sql) and the import it back. See [Run the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx). There are also 3rd party tools, like [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/).

Comment: +1 the only sensible way to go here

Comment: First I exported the database by script but on destination, while inserting it shows some foreign key violation.

How can I handle such issue?

Show I follow a sequence to insert data?

Comment: You are going to fix each issue individually, depending on what the issue is. The sequence of operations is entirely dependent on your data and  constraints, which obviously you do know while we do not.

Answer (score -1):

Steps to migrate:

1) get the list of tables in which entry was made before in SQL Server 2012

2) Generate the scripts in SQL Server 2012 and in advance option select "data only" for export type

3) using python run the SQL statements with reference to list of step 1 insert values in SQL Server 2008