# Can I use SQL Server Management Studio 2008 for 2012 DB?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

This is required because all developers are on Windows XP desktops and SSMS 2012 is not supported on XP. All developers have SSMS 2008 installed on their desktop. If one could connect from SSMS 2008 to SQL Server 2012, what are the limitations - if any ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10303791/62576

Comment: This is different .. development will be done against 2012 and deployed to 2012 but developers desktop is XP and thus they cannot run Server Studio 2012 but only 2008

Comment: The linked answer explains that this will work, but **only** if no SQL Server 2012 specific features are used. In what way is that different? If the developers are using SS2008, they cannot add or use any SS2012 features anyway. If they need 2012 features, they cannot use SSMS 2008. That should be clear from the answer to the question I linked.

Comment: Windows XP stopped receiving security updates in April 8th 2014

Comment: The world has changed. If you are looking for alternatives, you can use Azure Data Studio on Linux to connect to SQL Server. I never would have picked this back in the windows XP days. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15#download-azure-data-studio

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. 
It's not supported.
Unless they released an Update/ServicePack that I don't know anything about..

You need to install SSMS 2012.
Since you can't do that on XP, maybe Navicat works.

Comment: But you can use SSMS2012 on a 2008 DB. The tools know how to connect to the matching level DB and older.